# PLY installation is not properly

Tags: python, ply

I am trying to install PLY by `python setup.py install` as in the tutorial using git bash, but the result is not the same.

`python setup.py install` output:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
creating c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ply
copying build\lib\ply\cpp.py -> c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ply
copying build\lib\ply\ctokens.py -> c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ply
copying build\lib\ply\lex.py -> c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ply
copying build\lib\ply\yacc.py -> c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ply
copying build\lib\ply\__init__.py -> c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ply
byte-compiling c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ply\cpp.py to cpp.pyc
byte-compiling c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ply\ctokens.py to ctokens.pyc
byte-compiling c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ply\lex.py to lex.pyc
byte-compiling c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ply\yacc.py to yacc.pyc
byte-compiling c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ply\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
running install_egg_info
Writing c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ply-3.4-py2.7.egg-info
```

I can't even use PLY as shown at https://github.com/dabeaz/ply

```
import ply.lex as lex
```

I get the error `command not found`.

Comment: Where you enter the command `import ply.lex as lex`? Because `command not found` is not the Python message. You need to create a `.py` file and add `import ply.lex as lex` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it someone cares, i solved that, i just installed [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)